# Killed the sessions, Restarted the Database but not able to delete the user Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

There were some uncontrollable front end ODBC/JDBC connections to a user(Eg. ENT) in oracle 11g, I killed the sessions but since the front end was reconnecting, I changed the password of it. 
Later i was able to kill all the sessions completely and couldnt see any sessions in V$SESSION.
But still I'm not able to drop the user. I requested a DB restart to the DBA still no luck.
DB restart was done with shutdown immediate command and start respectively

Comment: What is the error when you do `DROP USER username CASCADE`?

Comment: I get the error:- ORA-01940: cannot drop a user that is currently connected

Comment: Are you using a RAC? Maybe there is a session on a different instance? I would also lock the account instead of just changing the password.

Comment: To have a clean shutdown, you MUST perform either SHUTDOWN or SHUTDOWN NORMAL. If you reach the 1 hour time-out, the database is telling you something is pending. DBA's often use IMMEDIATE because "it is faster". Just ask them what is the difference between NORMAL and IMMEDIATE. The way they react, will tell a lot.

Answer (score 0):

just shut it down and open it up restrict

```
shutdown immediate
startup restrict
drop user username cascade;
shutdown immediate
startup
```